# Is gcc doing implicit function declarations incorrectly in c99 mode?

Tags: gcc, standards, c99, c89

Consider the following code:

```
int main (void) {
    int i = xyzzy();
    return i;
}
int xyzzy (void) {
    return 42;
}
```

Now, although the prototype for `xyyzy` is unkown at the point of use, this works in c89 mode because the default return type of a function that has no prototype is `int` so the implicit function prototype and actual function are compatible.

And, in fact, if you change the return type of the function to `float`, you get (as expected):

```
testprog.c:6: error: conflicting types for 'xyzzy'
testprog.c:2: error: previous implicit declaration of 'xyzzy' was here
```

because the implicit prototype and actual function no longer match.

The original code compiled with `gcc --std=c89 --pedantic -Wall -Wextra` only gives me the warning:

```
testprog.c: In function 'main':
testprog.c:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'xyzzy'
```

which is expected, because c89 has this to say in `3.7.1 Function definitions`:

> **extern int max(int a, int b) { ... }:** Here `extern` is the storage-class specifier and `int` is the type specifier (each of which may be omitted as those are the defaults).

and in `3.3.2.2 Function calls`:

> If the expression that precedes the parenthesized argument list in a function call consists solely of an identifier, and if no declaration is visible for this identifier, the identifier is implicitly declared exactly as if, in the innermost block containing
>   the function call, the declaration **extern int identifier();** appeared.

So the use of a function before declaring it *definitely* results in the default prototype being created.

---

However, both those phrases have been removed in c99 and we instead find in `6.5.2.2 Function calls` (my bold):

> If the expression that denotes the called function has type pointer to function returning an object type, the function call expression has the same type as that object type, and has the value determined as specified in 6.8.6.4. **Otherwise, the function call has type void.**

I understand it to mean that, if there's no declaration in view when you try to call a function, it's implicitly declared with a `void` return type.

Yet, when compiling with `gcc --std=c99 --pedantic -Wall -Wextra`, I get just the same warning about the implicit declaration.

Shouldn't c99 have declared that function implicitly as returning `void`? If it had, I would have expected a `previous implicit declaration` error similar to the one I got when I tried to redeclare it as returning `float`.

Is `gcc` broken here, or am I missing something in the standard?

Comment: sun/oracle cc compiler with -xc99 option and using float for the func gives        current : function(void) returning float; 
        previous: function() returning int : "pax.c", line 2 ; I think it's hard 2 different compilers exhibit the same misinterpretation of the standard, even if it is not impossible - standards should avoid a language that makes it hard to get how things are supposed to be!

Comment: @Shin, that makes it look like the Sun compiler also defaults to "return int" even in C99 mode, in which case it may be I'm reading the standard incorrectly. I just couldn't figure out where.

Comment: You're reading couldn't be correct; it would not be backward compatible.  In C99, you're supposed to have a declaration (preferably a prototype declaration) of the function, or the function definition, visible in the scope. No declaration in scope requires a diagnostic (and could fail the compilation).  I note that you're quoting from the C89 ANSI standard — the section numbers in ISO C90 were different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in a note to **6.5.1 Primary expressions**:

> 2 - An identifier is a primary expression, provided it has been declared as designating an
>   object (in which case it is an lvalue) or a function (in which case it is a function
>   designator). <sup>79)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 79) Thus, an undeclared identifier is a violation of the syntax.

A conforming implementation is required by **5.1.1.3 Diagnostics** to produce a diagnostic message in response to the syntax violation of a function call expression involving an undeclared identifier as the expression denoting the called function.  It is of course free to proceed to compile the program as if the identifier had been declared in the implicit-`int` C89 style.

The paragraph 6.5.2.2p5 must be read with reference to the constraint 6.5.2.2p1:

> 1 - The expression that denotes the called function shall have type pointer to function
>   returning `void` or returning an object type other than an array type.

So, if the "*expression that denotes the called function*" does *not* have type "*pointer to function returning an object type*", it must *ipso facto* (by the constraint 6.5.2.2p1) have type "*pointer to function returning `void`*", and it is this case which the "*Otherwise*" in 6.5.2.2p5 covers.  That is, with my insertion in *[square brackets]*:

> 5 - If the expression that denotes the called function has type pointer to function returning an object type, the function call expression has the same type as that object type, and has the value determined as specified in 6.8.6.4. **Otherwise, *[i.e. if the expression that denotes the called function has type pointer to function returning `void`,]* the function call has type `void`**.

This is a case of special language being required for `void` as opposed to object types;  is not a licence for the called function expression to be or contain an undeclared identifier.

Answer (score 4):

You are reading the standard incorrectly. There's no such thing as implicit function declaration in C. It is removed from the language by C99.

GCC issues a warning when it sees an erroneous construct that looks like an implicit function declaration. This is OK as far as the standard is concerned. The standard requires a diagnostic here, and a warning is a diagnostic. You may use `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` flag to GCC to turn this into an error.

Comment: I wasn't actually after an unsupported assertion, I can get those anywhere :-) Can you point to the part of the standard that states this, and how does that reconcile with the quote from 6.5.2.2?

Comment: The standard per se says not a whole lot on things which are not in the language. You may find a few references in the surrounding literature, such as committee drafts. I think it's in the foreword of the actual standard too, but I'm not too sure. 6.5.2.2 is about deriving the type of a call-expression from the type of the function and does not mention declarations anywhere.